# ¿Cómo sumar datos de una tabla dinámica en js?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, tablas

Quiero sumar los datos de la última columna (VALOR TOTAL), pero no sé cómo, agradecería su ayuda, cuando hago **console.log** me muestra los valores de las celdas, pero aún no sé como sumar dichos valores, no.

Necesito de verdad una ayuda, para que me aclaren más esa parte, tengo varios métodos en mente, pero no sé a ciencia cierta cual y como implementarlo.

CODIGO HTML
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

CODIGO JS

```
var b = document.getElementById("add_item");

function factura()
{
  //carga de la tabla
  var t = document.getElementById("items_table");
  //variables de los campos de texto
  var cantidad = document.getElementById("cant").value;
  var articulo = document.getElementById("item").value;
  var precio = document.getElementById("price").value;
  //operacion para hallar el total de cada producto
  var txa = precio * cantidad;
  //variables de las celdas
  var fila = document.createElement("tr");
  var celda1 = document.createElement("td");
  var celda2 = document.createElement("td");
  var celda3 = document.createElement("td");
  var celda4 = document.createElement("td");
  //guardado de los valores de los campos de texto en una celda
  celda1.innerHTML = cantidad;
  celda2.innerHTML = articulo;
  celda3.innerHTML = precio;
  celda4.innerHTML = txa;
  //creacion de filas de la celda
  fila.appendChild(celda1);
  fila.appendChild(celda2);
  fila.appendChild(celda3);
  fila.appendChild(celda4);
  //insercion de la fila a la tabla
  t.appendChild(fila);
}

b.addEventListener("click", factura);
```

```
<div class="up">
    <h2>Lista de compra</h2>
      <div class="fields">
        <h3>Producto</h3>
        <input type="text" id="item" size="20">
      </div>
      <div class="fields">
        <h3>Precio</h3>
        <input type="number" id="price" size="20">
      </div>
      <div class="fields">
        <h3>Cantidad</h3>
      <input type="number" id="cant" size="20">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add_item" type="submit" value="Agregar">
  </div>
  <div class="down">
    <table border="1" id="items_table" width="600px">
      <caption>Factura</caption>
      <tr>
        <th>CANTIDAD</th><th>PRODUCTO</th><th>VALOR UNITARIO</th><th>VALOR TOTAL</th>
        <script src="../js/didactico.js"></script>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Agrega el código HTML como texto, también, no como imagen.

Comment: No me deja, porque es mucho codigo

Comment: Entonces sólo agrega la parte importante que tenga que ver con el enunciado de la pregunta. Lo mismo con el *script*.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias,agradeceria una ayuda con el codigo tambien

Answer (score 0):

Si te entiendo bien y lo que necesitas es una sumatoria de todos los productos que vas agregando, esta es una aproximación a ello.

```js
var b = document.getElementById("add_item");
var valorTotal = 0;
function factura()
{
  //carga de la tabla
  var t = document.getElementById("items_table");
  //variables de los campos de texto
  var cantidad = document.getElementById("cant").value;
  var articulo = document.getElementById("item").value;
  var precio = document.getElementById("price").value;
  //operacion para hallar el total de cada producto
  var txa = precio * cantidad;
  //variables de las celdas
  var fila = document.createElement("tr");
  var celda1 = document.createElement("td");
  var celda2 = document.createElement("td");
  var celda3 = document.createElement("td");
  var celda4 = document.createElement("td");
  //guardado de los valores de los campos de texto en una celda
  celda1.innerHTML = cantidad;
  celda2.innerHTML = articulo;
  celda3.innerHTML = precio;
  celda4.innerHTML = txa;
  //creacion de filas de la celda
  fila.appendChild(celda1);
  fila.appendChild(celda2);
  fila.appendChild(celda3);
  fila.appendChild(celda4);
  //insercion de la fila a la tabla
  t.appendChild(fila);
  valorTotal += txa;
  document.getElementById("totalCompra").innerText = valorTotal;
}

b.addEventListener("click", factura);
```

```html
<div class="up">
  <h2>Lista de compra</h2>
  <div class="fields">
    <h3>Producto</h3>
    <input type="text" id="item" size="20">
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
    <h3>Precio</h3>
    <input type="number" id="price" size="20">
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
    <h3>Cantidad</h3>
    <input type="number" id="cant" size="20">
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="add_item" type="submit" value="Agregar">
</div>
<div class="down">
  <div>Total compra: <span id="totalCompra">0</span></div>
  <table border="1" id="items_table" width="600px">
    <caption>Factura</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>CANTIDAD</th><th>PRODUCTO</th><th>VALOR UNITARIO</th><th>VALOR TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas muchisimas gracias bro, si sospechaba que era por esa parte, pero no supe como cuadrar la sintaxis del +=. Se que esa expresion suma dos veces el valor o variable, pero no me acordaba si eso que queria sumar tenia que ir a la derecha o a la izquierda.